# Call to API via postman works fine but not in my app

Tags: c#, api, postman

I have made a successful call to a rest API in postman.

I have copied the c# code postman generates and put it in my own c# web API but it fails.

Reporting bad request.

Am I missing something, will postman be doing something extra I'm not aware of.

**POSTMAN**
Headers...

```
Content-Type : application/json
```

Body...

```
{  
   "key":"value",
   "key":"value",
   "key":value,
   "key":"value",
   "key":"{key:value}"
}
```

The above runs fine...

My Web API...

```
       string json = " { ";

        json += " \"key\":\"value\", ";
        json += " \"key\":\"value\", ";
        json += " \"key\":\"value\", ";
        json += " \"key\":\"value\", ";
        json += " \"key\":\"{ key: value}\"";

        json += " } ";


        var client = new RestClient("url");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This returns...

```
StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: text/html, Content-Length: -1)
```

Comment: Can we see the request ? in code .

Comment: Sure, we can help with code we can't see.  It's also helpful that you included the error information.   http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: I have updated the post, thanks guys

Comment: You could hook up Fiddler or some other HttpProxy, and compare the requests

Comment: Is that literally the message body that works in Postman? That is not valid json.

Comment: Well I have removed the sensitive info and replaced the param names with 'key' and the param values with 'value'. When put through a Json beautifier it is valid Json

Comment: So this (mocked) value is correct?  "key":"{key:value}"  . It is not supposed to be  "key":{ "key" : "value" }  ?

Comment: Yes thats right, its like this...
"Key":"{Key:Value}"

Comment: I thought it was strange too

Comment: I only made the one comment.  It's unclear why you think I need to "chill out".  I have removed my downvote now that you have added useful information to the question, despite your "chill out" comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all that, all it needed was the url to be https:// not http:// :(

Just in case it helps anyone else in the future, in postman the url was just set as domain.co.uk but in my code I had put http://domain.co.uk for the base url of the API, so the API required all calls to be made using SSL.

Postman must do SSL by default. As soon as I set my app to https:// it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you @Matthew Stott. In my case, I was calling an API hosted on https from localhost which is not on https. So, I switched to console application for calling the API as I just wanted to run it in background and its worked :)